# How to Fix the header of Facelets Template?

Tags: css, jsf-2, facelets

I'm using primefaces 3.5. I want my Facelets Header to be Static like Facebook Header.So my content can be scrolled with a fixed header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had Same problem in Past. Assign your position to fixed `position:fixed` and make sure that your z-index value of header is lower than the z-index value of content in css.so that your content will not scroll over the header.

Example:

```
.header{ position:fixed; z-index:1;}
.content{ position:absolute; z-index:2;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing specific to Primefaces or either JSF here. It should simply be a matter of applying the correct css style.

For example:

```
<style>.header{position: fixed; top: 0;}</style>
<div class="header"></div>
```

See also:

- [MDN CSS position reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning)